# Can i add a Slide show to my website in a block. Is it possible for my Theme

Tags: javascript

I would like to add  slide show to my website. How can i do that. And i would like to add it as a block in all the pages. What is the easy way to do that.

Please suggest.

Comment: "Easiest" is entirely opinion-based. And we don't suggest here, we answer questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is [Views sldieshow module](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)
, create a views just in block . the screen cast is [this](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-slideshow/)  and a lot more
and another help to choose a good slideshow module is this [page](http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/5-best-drupal-slideshows)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the Fields slideshow module https://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow and optionally the Colorbox module.

Create a content type with an image field. Configure it so that you can load infinite images. Set the formatter of the image field as "slideshow". Then create a block with views and display the block in your sidebar.

Here is a good screencast to set it up: http://vimeo.com/26411524